# an eigen value problem of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a matrix of order n such that sum of elements of each row is zero. Prove that 0 is an eigenvalue of the matrix. I think logically like this.. As 0 is the sum of all elements of row 1/0 is the sum of all elements of the row of inverse of A. which contradicts the existence of the inverse. Now if 0 is the eigenvalue of A 1/0 is an eigenvalue of the inverse matrix.. which also contradict the existence of inverse.. hence 0 is eigenvalue of A. Maybe it is wrong method of proof..

Comment: What is the image of $(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$?

Comment: $A$ doesn't even have an inverse because the sum of all the columns of $A$ is the column which elements are $0$ (that's because the sum of the elements of of each row is $0$). Thus the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent. Hence $A$ doesn't have inverse (in fact the linearly dependence of the columns of $A$ implies $\det A$ if $\det$ is seen as an alternative multilinear n-form).

Comment: Even if $\;A\;$ had an inverse, you can **not** deduce that if a row sum of $\;A\;$ is zero then a row (or even a column) sum of $\;A^{-1}\;$ is zero

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things that are wrong with your proof:

- It is *not* true that if the sum of the first row of $A$ is zero, then the sum of the first row of $A^{-1}$ is zero (if $A^{-1}$) exists.
- You can't divide by zero.  Just because you decided to divide by zero, however, doesn't mean you've reached a contradiction.

Here's an easy method of proof:

We note that $\lambda$ is an eigenvlaue of $A$ if and only if $A - \lambda I$ is non-invertible.  Note that $A(1,\dots,1)^T = 0$, so $A = A - 0I$ is not invertible. So, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Alternatively, see that the vector $v = (1,\dots,1)^T$ satisfies $Av = 0 \cdot v = 0$, so that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with the eigenvlaue $0$.  So, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.